# how to get a average of values except negative numbers in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which has has a column that i need to take the average but in my average i want to exclude minues numbers

im sure this im doing is wrong,but how can i do it?

```
     SELECT power_curve_quality where m_turbine_id='192.168.30.82'
     and m_date>='2020-08-01' and m_date<'2020-09-01' 
     FROM wh.t_statistics_daily_ext 
     EXCEPT select power_curve_quality<0 
     FROM wh.t_statistics_daily_ext 
    where m_turbine_id='192.168.30.82' and m_date>='2020-08-01' and m_date<'2020-09-01'
```

Comment: Should the table name `wh.t_statistics_daily_ext` be `t_statistics_daily_ext`? Possible typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the negative observations in the divisor, then this will do it:

```
select avg(greatest(power_curve_quality, 0))
  from t_statistics_daily_ext
 where . . .
```

If you want to exclude negative observations altogether, then use this:

```
select avg(power_curve_quality)
  from t_statistics_daily_ext
 where . . . 
   and power_curve_quality >= 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
create table avg(id int, fld_1 int);
insert into avg values(1, 2), (2, -1), (3, 4), (4, -4), (5, 3);
select avg(fld_1) from avg where fld_1 >= 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `power_curve_quality >= 0` into the `WHERE` clause like so:

```
SELECT
    avg(power_curve_quality)
FROM
    t_statistics_daily_ext
WHERE
    power_curve_quality >= 0 
    and m_turbine_id = '192.168.30.82'
    and m_date >= '2020-08-01'
    and m_date < '2020-09-01' 
    ;
```